# Can performance of image conversion from "Byte" to "Real32" image via lookup table be improved?

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

Are there any other techniques I could use to improve the performance of the below timed operation that converts a "Byte" type Grayscale image to "Real32" using the given lookup table.

I've tried using **ImageApply** with a compiled function to perform the lookup, but that is actually a bit slower.

```
testImage = Image[RandomImage[1, {1600, 1600*4}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"], "Byte"];

decompandImage[img_?ImageQ] :=
  With[{lut = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
   16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39,
    41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 67, 71, 75, 
   79, 83, 87, 91, 95, 99, 103, 107, 111, 115, 119, 123, 127, 131,
    135, 139, 143, 147, 151, 155, 159, 163, 167, 171, 175, 179, 
   183, 187, 191, 195, 199, 203, 207, 211, 215, 219, 223, 227, 
   231, 235, 239, 243, 247, 255, 263, 271, 279, 287, 295, 303, 
   311, 319, 327, 335, 343, 351, 359, 367, 375, 383, 391, 399, 
   407, 415, 423, 431, 439, 447, 455, 463, 471, 479, 487, 495, 
   503, 511, 519, 527, 535, 543, 551, 559, 567, 575, 583, 591, 
   599, 607, 615, 623, 631, 639, 647, 655, 663, 671, 679, 687, 
   695, 703, 711, 719, 727, 735, 743, 751, 759, 767, 775, 783, 
   791, 799, 807, 815, 823, 831, 839, 847, 855, 863, 871, 879, 
   887, 895, 903, 911, 919, 927, 935, 943, 951, 959, 967, 975, 
   983, 991, 999, 1007, 1023, 1039, 1055, 1071, 1087, 1103, 1119, 
   1135, 1151, 1167, 1183, 1199, 1215, 1231, 1247, 1263, 1279, 
   1295, 1311, 1327, 1343, 1359, 1375, 1391, 1407, 1439, 1471, 
   1503, 1535, 1567, 1599, 1631, 1663, 1695, 1727, 1759, 1791, 
   1823, 1855, 1887, 1919, 1951, 1983, 2015, 2047, 2079, 2111, 
   2143, 2175, 2207, 2239, 2271, 2303, 2335, 2367, 2399, 2431, 
   2463, 2495, 2527, 2559, 2591, 2623, 2655, 2687, 2719, 2751, 
   2783, 2815, 2847, 2879}/2879. (* // N // Developer`ToPackedArray *)
  },
  Image[Map[lut[[# + 1]] &, ImageData[img, "Byte"], {2}], "Real32"]
  ];

AbsoluteTiming[test4 = decompandImage[testImage]] [[1]]
```

Comment: Remove {2} will make it bit faster i think, with same result. Also you should move `+ 1`  so you have `ImageData[img, "Byte"] + 1`

Comment: Thanks @Coolwater. Removing the '{2}' gave a significant improvement. Moving the +1 was produced either no change or a slight slow-down.

Comment: Just changing the code after LUT definition to `Image[Partition[lut[[Join @@ ImageData[img, "Byte"] + 1]], 
   First@ImageDimensions@img], "Real32"]]` should speed things nicely...

Comment: Thank for your input @ciao.  Your suggestion runs .28s, slightly faster than my initial implementation, but significantly slower than Coolwater and Henrick's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildung on [Coolwater](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9754/coolwater)'s comment, one can obtain a slight improvement by compiling this into a `Listable` and parallelized `CompiledFunction`:

```
clookup = Compile[{{lut, _Real, 1}, {x, _Integer, 1}},
   lut[[x + 1]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

lut = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
    18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 
    45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79, 83, 87, 
    91, 95, 99, 103, 107, 111, 115, 119, 123, 127, 131, 135, 139, 143,
     147, 151, 155, 159, 163, 167, 171, 175, 179, 183, 187, 191, 195, 
    199, 203, 207, 211, 215, 219, 223, 227, 231, 235, 239, 243, 247, 
    255, 263, 271, 279, 287, 295, 303, 311, 319, 327, 335, 343, 351, 
    359, 367, 375, 383, 391, 399, 407, 415, 423, 431, 439, 447, 455, 
    463, 471, 479, 487, 495, 503, 511, 519, 527, 535, 543, 551, 559, 
    567, 575, 583, 591, 599, 607, 615, 623, 631, 639, 647, 655, 663, 
    671, 679, 687, 695, 703, 711, 719, 727, 735, 743, 751, 759, 767, 
    775, 783, 791, 799, 807, 815, 823, 831, 839, 847, 855, 863, 871, 
    879, 887, 895, 903, 911, 919, 927, 935, 943, 951, 959, 967, 975, 
    983, 991, 999, 1007, 1023, 1039, 1055, 1071, 1087, 1103, 1119, 
    1135, 1151, 1167, 1183, 1199, 1215, 1231, 1247, 1263, 1279, 1295, 
    1311, 1327, 1343, 1359, 1375, 1391, 1407, 1439, 1471, 1503, 1535, 
    1567, 1599, 1631, 1663, 1695, 1727, 1759, 1791, 1823, 1855, 1887, 
    1919, 1951, 1983, 2015, 2047, 2079, 2111, 2143, 2175, 2207, 2239, 
    2271, 2303, 2335, 2367, 2399, 2431, 2463, 2495, 2527, 2559, 2591, 
    2623, 2655, 2687, 2719, 2751, 2783, 2815, 2847, 2879}/2879.;

cdecompandImage[img_?ImageQ] := Image[clookup[lut, ImageData[img, "Byte"]], "Real32"];
```

Comment: Thanks @Henrick, that compilation style also produced a significant improvement.  My function -> .33s , Removing {2} -> .16s , compiled/listable -> .10s

Comment: `Image[ImageApply[lut[[#*255 + 1]] &, Image[testImage, "Bit16"]], "Real32"]` - though serial - is very fast as well, however does not give exactly the same result as above, as 16bit requantisation is being done, but no grayscale level is being lost for the given lut. However `Image[ImageApply[lut[[#*255 + 1]] &, testImage], "Real32"]` would do 8bit requantisation, so many grayscale levels would get lost for this lut. Is there any particular reason why Real32 requested? Bit16 is sufficient in many practical cases, so the back casting could be skipped.